# How to make dynamic column range for splitting string on comma

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will go into a workbook, find cells that have a comma in them, split them and paste them starting at the last row in that column. The code below somewhat works but

1. It's limited in terms of changing the column range every time (a,b,c,etc). How do I dynamic, meaning run on multiple columns regardless of wherever the data starts?
2. Only start after the first row since I have headers.
3. The actual code below is a bit slow, what can I do to have it run more efficiently?

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim myarray As Variant
    
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A:A")
    
    For Each rCell In rRng
        If InStr(1, rCell, ",") > 0 Then
        myarray = Split(rCell, ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = myarray(i)
Next
        Else
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to reimplement [`TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns)?

Comment: You want to run this on a sheet and have it process all values with commas on that sheet, regardless of where they're located?  Do your sheets contain any formulas?

Comment: @TimWilliams no formulas in the sheets

Comment: You can loop over the sheet's `UsedRange.Columns` collection

Answer (score 0):

### Split Cell Values

[image]

---

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSplitsTEST()
    
    ' The number of empty rows between the source (initial) data
    ' and the destination (resulting) data.
    Const EmptyRows As Long = 0
    Const Delimiter As String = ","
    
    ' Create a reference to the range.
    Dim rg As Range
    With Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        'Debug.Print .Address ' with headers
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        'Debug.Print rg.Address ' without headers
    End With
    
    ' Use the 'GetSplits' function to get the result in an array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetSplits(rg, Delimiter)
    
    ' Validate the array.
    If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then
        ' Write the result below the range.
        rg.Cells(1).Offset(rg.Rows.Count + EmptyRows) _
            .Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End If

End Sub

Function GetSplits( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As Variant
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim sData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 And cCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        sData = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim cDat As Variant: ReDim cDat(1 To cCount, 1 To 3)
    Dim rDat As Variant: ReDim rDat(1 To rCount)
    Dim c As Long, sr As Long, n As Long, drCount As Long, maxCount As Long
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        drCount = 0
        cDat(c, 1) = rDat
        cDat(c, 2) = rDat
        n = 0
        For sr = 1 To rCount
            If InStr(1, sData(sr, c), Delimiter) > 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                cDat(c, 1)(n) = Split(sData(sr, c), Delimiter)
                cDat(c, 2)(n) = UBound(cDat(c, 1)(n))
                drCount = drCount + cDat(c, 2)(n) + 1
            End If
        Next sr
        cDat(c, 3) = n
        If drCount > maxCount Then
            maxCount = drCount
        End If
    Next c

    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To maxCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        dr = 0
        For n = 1 To cDat(c, 3)
            For sr = 0 To cDat(c, 2)(n)
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, c) = cDat(c, 1)(n)(sr)
            Next sr
        Next n
    Next c
    
    GetSplits = dData

End Function
```